# window.print() duplicating pages on JS

Tags: javascript, printing, window

I'm using a function to print a Modal, and it's returning with a duplicate.

The Function:

function printElement(btnVal)
{
// $('.abrirLogs').trigger( "click" );

```
// REMOVE OS ELEMENTOS DESNECESSÁRIOS
  $('html').find('.remove_on_print').remove();

// VERIFICA QUAL A DESPESA QUE ESTÁ SENDO VISUALIZADA
  $('html').find('.despCard').each(function (i, val) {
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });

document.title = `Relatório do Pedido de Despesa # ${$('#pedidoIdentif').val()} - Despesa ${$('.despCount'+btnVal).val()}`;

parent.$('title').get(0).innerHTML = 'relatorio_pedido_despesa' + $('#despID').val();

console.log(window);

window.print();

parent.$('title').get(0).innerHTML = 'Pedidos Aprovados';

location.reload();

return true;
```

};

[[The print popup images:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbdpC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHdVq.png)

I've look for the same problem but couldn´t find the answer.